# Arrastar item do ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Alguém saberia me dizer como faço para arrastar um item do ListView para um lado ou para o outro? De preferência uma forma que sirva para o Cross-Platform Android/IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por enquanto a implementação default do ListView do xamarin-forms não suporta isso. Você teria que implementar um customizado. Ou então usar componentes de terceiros. Dá uma olhada aqui https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin

Comment: Ah sim, achei que tivesse isso implementado já :D
Valeu por ajudar vou dar uma olhada no link